# Reorder table row using sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am maintain paging order in the table like `"PrevRunActivityNo"` and `"NextRunActivityNo"` columns. In that table rows are added dynamical and update their `PrevRunActivityNo` and `NextRunActivityNo` order. Now I am to fetch rows as per there `NextRunActivityNo` order

Here I attach my table records

[image]

As per the image, I need to order records as per `NextRunActivityNo`.

Can anyone give me proper solution for that.

Comment: can you please provide your sample data as `text` instead `image link`

Comment: check this link hope this will help you https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/182659/reorder-records-in-table

Comment: `ORDER BY NextRunActivityNo` ??

Comment: can you please show us your database, i mean how it is like in database as well as code to fetch the table

Comment: @Arvind , please check the solution for your issue , if it is correct then please up vote this answer

Answer (score 0):

Please run the below query after replacing **ActivityTable** in query with your actual table name.

```
USE [Your DataBase]

SELECT *
FROM ActivityTable
ORDER BY NextRunActivityNo DESC
```